# Can't draw shapes in java

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics, jframe

I'm pretty sure that this code should draw an oval on the screen next to the word text. However, the word is all the appears, the rest of the screen is black. This seems to happen with any primitive shape. I'd like to think I know java fairly well, but graphical things have been really confusing to me. I'm at my wit's end with this and any help would be appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    int W = 4;
    int H = 3;
    int windowSize = 300;
    boolean running;
    static boolean drawHitBoxes = true;
    int FPSLimit = 30;

    private Thread thread;
    private BufferedImage buffer;
    private Graphics2D g;

    public Game() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(W * windowSize, H * windowSize));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        running = true;

        buffer = new BufferedImage(W * windowSize, H * windowSize,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = (Graphics2D) buffer.getGraphics();

        // citList.add(new Citizen(200, 200, "Joe"));

        long startTime;
        long waitTime;

        long frameTime = 1000 / FPSLimit; // /How long one frame should take
        long currentFrameTime;

        while (running) {
            startTime = System.nanoTime(); // record when loop starts

            gameUpdate();
            gameRender();
            gameDraw();

            // Calculate how long the current frame took
            currentFrameTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
            waitTime = frameTime - currentFrameTime;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } // Sleep for the remaining time
        }
    }

    private void gameUpdate() {
        // for(Citizen i:citList){i.update();} //Update citizens
    }

    private void gameRender() {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawOval(100, 100, W - 100, H - 100);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("Text.", 100, 100);
        System.out.println("Drawing white box.");

        // for(Citizen i:citList){i.draw(g);} //Draw citizens
    }

    private void gameDraw() {
        Graphics gMain = this.getGraphics();
        gMain.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see edit to answer. You likely want: `g.drawOval(100, 100, W * windowSize - 200, H * windowSize - 200);`

Comment: My god, I can't believe I did that and couldn't see it. This is horribly embarrassing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
g.drawOval(100, 100, W-100, H-100);
```

W is 4 and H is 3, and so since `W-100` is -96 and `H-100` is -97, making your 3rd and 4th parameters negative, which doesn't make sense for the `Graphics#drawOval(...)` method since how can an oval's width and height be negative. Solution: be sure to use only positive parameters that make sense when calling this method. Probably what you want is:

```
 // but you'll also want to avoid magic numbers such as 100 & 200 as well
 g.drawOval(100, 100, W * windowSize - 200, H * windowSize - 200);
```

As an aside, myself, I prefer using passive graphics, drawing in paintComponent and am fearful whenever I see Swing code that has a Graphics or Graphics2D instance field.. Also your code looks to not obey Swing threading rules as it appears to be making Swing calls off of the Swing event thread.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to create the paintComponent method and transfer your gameRender and gameDraw there and in your while loop replace their method calls with repaint(). Here is the code that works.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    int W = 4;
    int H = 3;
    int windowSize = 300;
    boolean running;
    static boolean drawHitBoxes = true;
    int FPSLimit = 30;

    private Thread thread;
    private BufferedImage buffer;
    private Graphics2D g;

    public Game() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(W * windowSize, H * windowSize));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        running = true;

        buffer = new BufferedImage(W * windowSize, H * windowSize,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = (Graphics2D) buffer.getGraphics();

        // citList.add(new Citizen(200, 200, "Joe"));

        long startTime;
        long waitTime;

        long frameTime = 1000 / FPSLimit; // /How long one frame should take
        long currentFrameTime;

        while (running) {
            startTime = System.nanoTime(); // record when loop starts

            gameUpdate();
            //gameRender();
            //gameDraw();
            repaint();

            // Calculate how long the current frame took
            currentFrameTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
            waitTime = frameTime - currentFrameTime;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } // Sleep for the remaining time
        }
    }

    private void gameUpdate() {
        // for(Citizen i:citList){i.update();} //Update citizens
    }

    private void gameRender() {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        //g.drawOval(100, 100, W - 100, H - 100);
        g.drawOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("Text.", 100, 100);
        //System.out.println("Drawing white box.");

        // for(Citizen i:citList){i.draw(g);} //Draw citizens
    }

    private void gameDraw(Graphics gMain) {
        //Graphics gMain = this.getGraphics();
        gMain.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        gameRender();
        gameDraw(g);
    }
}
```

As point out by @Hovercraft in his answer, the W-100 and H-100 in the code `g.drawOval(100, 100, W - 100, H - 100);' will yield negative numbers. I don't know exactly what values do you want to result in there but I just replace them with 100 just to remove the bug.

Comment: Unlike AWT programs, you should almost *never* call `updateUI()` on Swing components, unless you're doing so after changing the Look & Feel.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels why is it? Does this create delays?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. What's the best way to trigger the protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) on this example?

Comment: I updated my answer and change updateUI() to repaint()

Comment: I like that better, 1+. Please see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more on `update()` usage in Swing and AWT.